# $\text{lim inf}_{t \downarrow 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{t}E[X_{s}^{2}]ds}{t^{2}}\leq \text{lim sup}_{t \downarrow 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{t}E[X_{s}^{2}]ds}{t^{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $g(t) = E[X_{t}^{2}]$, the starting point is the following set of inequalities which hold for all $t \geq 0$: 
\begin{align}
- \int _{0}^{t} 2g(s)ds + t \leq g(t) \leq \int _{0}^{t} 2g(s)ds + t
\end{align}

Then, we need to prove the following:\begin{align}
0 < \text{lim inf}_{t \downarrow 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{t}E[X_{s}^{2}]ds}{t^{2}}\leq \text{lim sup}_{t \downarrow 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{t}E[X_{s}^{2}]ds}{t^{2}} < \infty
\end{align}

An obvious first step is integrating the above inequalities, and Fubini will probably also be useful, since then you can exchange the expectation and integrals. Furtermore, $X_{t}$ is also a submartingale, but I am not sure if that is relevant here.

However, even with the above knowledge I still can not picture where the limsup and liminf in the expression come from.

I would really appreciate any help.

**EDIT**: As per TheBridges' request, I also give the SDE of $X_{t}$ below, though I am not sure if it is relevant towards answering my question. 
\begin{align}
dX_{t} = |X_{t}|dt + dW_{t}, X_{0} = 0
\end{align}

To derive the first inequalities at the top, I applied Ito to rewrite $X_{t}^2$, and together with the SDE of $X_{t}$ you can fairly easily derive these inequalities. But it is still unclear as to how they should be used to derive the second set of inequalities.

Comment: Where your first two inequalities are coming from ?

Comment: The right hand side inequality seems dubious to me with $g(t)=t^2$, I get the condition $-2/3t^3+t<t^2$ equivalent for t>0 to $-2/3t^2+1<t$ which false for small t.

Comment: @TheBridge You mean the starting inequalities right? I just applied the Ito formula to $X_{t}^{2}$, and used the original SDE for $X_{t}$ to eventually get those inequalities. If you'd like I can edit those into the question, but sure if it's relevant.

Comment: Still not clear to what sde do you apply Itô's lemma to ? I don't see how those inequalities are derived from Itô maybe you could add those details in the question

Comment: @TheBridge Ok, I edited the question with the SDE.

Comment: As to what you wrote in your comment, "I don't see how...'. The fact is that for general "g", the inequality $\int _{0}^{t} 2g(s)ds + t \leq g(t)$ is false for the example I mentioned. That is why it is important to give more context to check that for your particular "g" of interest the claim is true.

Comment: @TheBridge But I never claimed that it holds for all $g$, only for the particular one I mentioned in the exercise, i.e. $g(t) = E[X_{t}^{2}]$. It is definitely correct that it holds for this function, but my main concern is with the second set of inequalities.

Comment: As written in your question it is stated in full generality though ...

Comment: @TheBridge Sorry, but you are wrong. I clearly only mentioned one specific function, I just claimed it holds for all $t \geq 0$ for that specific function.

Comment: This is becoming childish if you can’t see why so be it